# Where can I find a >1K dataset of annotated store receipt pictures/scans?

Tags: dataset, computer-vision

I’m looking for a large dataset of store receipt pictures or scans. The image quality is not of the highest priority. However, some annotations would be nice:

- vendor
- date of purchase
- total amount
- (optional: tax amount)
- (optional: currency)
- (optional: list of each individual item with associated amount, price, discounts)

Comment: You might have more luck on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/